# Android delete firebase data using custom listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

Hello Everyone how i can delete on click item from custom listview. i am unable to delete the firebase data.

Here is the Student Activity where all student will appear in custom listview i want to delete on click

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

```
    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("type").equalTo("student");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                ModelClass Mod = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ModelClass.class);
                list.add(Mod);

            }
            final CustomAdapterClassStudent adapterClassCompany = new CustomAdapterClassStudent(AllStudents.this , list);
            l1.setAdapter(adapterClassCompany);
            l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is my Custom Adapter class extend with Array Adapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    final View listview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter , null , true);
    TextView textViewName  = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.textName);
    TextView textViewAdd  = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.textAdd);
    TextView textViewBio  = (TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.textBio);

    final ModelClass Mod = compniesModel.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(Mod.name);
    textViewAdd.setText(Mod.cgpa);
    textViewBio.setText(Mod.bio);



    return listview;
```

Here is the ModelClass.. ModelClass contain student and company fields to save in firebase.. check image below

```
public class ModelClass {


public String name;
public String email;
public String cgpa;
public String age;
public String bio;


public String type;



public String compName;
public String compAdd;
public String compAbout;


public ModelClass(){}

public ModelClass(String name, String email, String cgpa, String age, String bio,String type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.cgpa = cgpa;
    this.age = age;
    this.bio = bio;
    this.type = type;
}

public ModelClass(String compName, String compAdd, String compAbout , String type) {
    this.compName = compName;
    this.compAdd = compAdd;
    this.compAbout = compAbout;
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

[Here is the Database Image Click on this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXs3a.png)

Comment: Can you show us your ModelClass ?

Comment: hey Pipiks, i add my ModelClass in question.. i properly able to save my data through ModelClass if user say "Company" in the firebase data save as type "company" otherwise "student".. but i am unable to delete where all my students appear in custom list.

Comment: if you say so i will update my code on GitHub so you can check my all codes.. it would be a pleasure to me if you help me.. i have wasted 4 hours but i failed myself now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the user key in your model, so add this :

```
public String key;
```

Then you can set the key :

```
ModelClass Mod = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ModelClass.class);
Mod.key = dataSnapshot1.getKey();

list.add(Mod);
```

And in your **onItemClick** you can now remove the current user :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    ModelClass model = list.get(i);
    list.remove(removePosition);

    databaseReference.child("users").child(model.key).removeValue();
}
```

**NOTE**

You should use childAdded event to not reload all your list when you remove a user.

You should also init your adapter only one time. In your completion update the list and call notifyDataChanged().

Comment: hey Pipiks, i successfully deleted my data onclick.. Thank you man your code help me :)

Comment: Can you please show me the initialization of 'databseReference'

Comment: databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Comment: You changed your previous comment, so everything is working ?

Comment: yes working.. i implement in my code as you told me above now it's working :)

Comment: I will take a look but please close this question by validate the answer.